# Existence of minimizing geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have read in [a post in Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/285g-lecture-1-ricci-flow/) that in every connected smooth manifold, any two points can be joined by $C^1$-piecewise minimising geodesic, but I am not so sure that this result is true in not necessarily complete manifolds, because otherwise we wouldn't need the completeness condition in the theorem of Hopf-Rinow.

> [image]

The classic counter-example is $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ in which any point and its central inversion can't be joined by a minimising geodesic. So if anybody can confirm or invalidate Tao's statement, it would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be right—he refers neither to completeness nor to compactness.